# npm - ENOENT, open <current_dir>/null

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and my npm stopped working:

`$ npm cache clean
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/jasonshark/null'`

I have npm 1.4.21 and node 0.10.30

Whenever I try to do anything with the npm I get null after the dir I'm in. what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, it's a nopt [bug](https://github.com/npm/nopt/commit/5a73af18de63a1552d056c13eef64f30bd8064ee#diff-59b8d3fa564f3d398f93362b1180e6ba)

Open `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmconf/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js` and at line 127

```
function validatePath (data, k, val) {
  if (val === true) return false
  if (val === null) return true // <-- ADD THIS LINE !
  data[k] = path.resolve(String(val))
  return true
}
```

[reference](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5613#issuecomment-48848753)

Comment: the code was slightly different in my version on node, but adding the line did the trick, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

[Check this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5613).  A range of solutions have been given.
This seems to fix it

```
sudo port uninstall npm
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/
sudo port install npm
```

Comment: port won't work cause i'm on ubuntu but uninstalling then reinstalling npm seems like a good idea

Comment: @ConnorLeech yeah try with `apt-get`and inform us.